# Flowlayout and Tablelayout in windows form

Tags: c#, .net, tablelayoutpanel, flowlayoutpanel, windows-controls

What is the difference between Flowlayout and Tablelayout in windows form ? I know i can google it, but i am bit short on time.

my requirement is too , that when the form is resized. Resizing for forms should not mess up my align for the control, it should react to resolution changes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`TableLayout` will keep your controls in a grid pattern, and will resized to fill the form (if docked to the parent container). A `FlowLayout` will place controls in a (by default) horizontal line, and wrap the controls to the next line if they don't all fit. The wrapping should happen dynamically as the panel is resized. You can also set it to wrap vertically.

It sounds like you should use a `TableLayout`.